# Using wordpress functions to add featured image to block

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Hi I'm a bit new with adding custom functions in my code but I'm building a blog and in the every post page has a button where it says previous or next article. I wanted to use that pre existing function but display a block with the featured image for the each previous/next post.

I'm using [Radcliffe theme](http://www.andersnoren.se/themes/radcliffe/our-last-summer/) and the arrows are in the bottom of the page. This is the part of the code I want to add the "block":

Thank you!

```
<div class="post-nav">  
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <p class="post-nav-next">
        <a title="<?php _e('Next post:', 'radcliffe'); echo ' ' . get_the_title($next_post); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($next_post); ?> </a>
    </p>                    
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>                      
    <p class="post-nav-prev">           
    <a title="<?php _e('Previous post:', 'radcliffe'); echo ' ' . get_the_title($prev_post); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($prev_post); ?> </a>
    </p>                
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: There is no Error I just want to add something